# process df with ddplyr

Tags: r, plyr

My df is like:

```
    L   T        m       EI      f.1      f.4      f.6      f.5      f.9
1  10 1.0 6.190004 9988.997  6.59710 13.38665 20.55083 28.25382 36.63822
6  10 3.5 6.190004 9988.997 12.11441 24.33067 36.74911 49.46745 62.58052
19 25 1.0 6.190004 9988.997  2.57757  5.16730  7.78128 10.43146 13.12981
24 25 3.5 6.190004 9988.997  4.79088  9.58822 14.39848 19.22824 24.08453
```

Now I want process this df with `ddplyr` as follow steps, escaping loop structures.

- create new named columns with a function: le.? = fun(f.?) (where is `?` is 1,4,6,5,9. And the column names are as `le.?`. The number followed `le` may change in another process.
- solve a equation `enfoo` based on parameters `L, T, f.?`, the root of each equation is bind to df

The poblems I meet in this proess are:

1. How to slice the columns named with `f.?` and use `ddplyr` to create new columns?
2. How to slice the columns `f.?` with accordingly the clomuns `le.?` where ?  the same number ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly then this might help.

Note that for demonstration purpose I have applied a simple function on `f.*` columns to create `le.*` columns. i.e. `l.* = (f.*) / 2`.

In below code you can replace this simple function with your defined function by tweaking `funs` parameter.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(f.1:f.9), funs(le=./2)) %>%
  rename_at(vars(f.1_le:f.9_le), funs(gsub("[a-zA-Z]+[.](\\d+)[_](\\S+)","\\2.\\1",.)))
```

**Output is:**

```
   L   T        m       EI      f.1      f.4      f.6      f.5      f.9     le.1      le.4     le.6     le.5
1 10 1.0 6.190004 9988.997  6.59710 13.38665 20.55083 28.25382 36.63822 3.298550  6.693325 10.27542 14.12691
2 10 3.5 6.190004 9988.997 12.11441 24.33067 36.74911 49.46745 62.58052 6.057205 12.165335 18.37456 24.73372
3 25 1.0 6.190004 9988.997  2.57757  5.16730  7.78128 10.43146 13.12981 1.288785  2.583650  3.89064  5.21573
4 25 3.5 6.190004 9988.997  4.79088  9.58822 14.39848 19.22824 24.08453 2.395440  4.794110  7.19924  9.61412
       le.9
1 18.319110
2 31.290260
3  6.564905
4 12.042265
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(L = c(10L, 10L, 25L, 25L), T = c(1, 3.5, 1, 3.5
), m = c(6.190004, 6.190004, 6.190004, 6.190004), EI = c(9988.997, 
9988.997, 9988.997, 9988.997), f.1 = c(6.5971, 12.11441, 2.57757, 
4.79088), f.4 = c(13.38665, 24.33067, 5.1673, 9.58822), f.6 = c(20.55083, 
36.74911, 7.78128, 14.39848), f.5 = c(28.25382, 49.46745, 10.43146, 
19.22824), f.9 = c(36.63822, 62.58052, 13.12981, 24.08453)), .Names = c("L", 
"T", "m", "EI", "f.1", "f.4", "f.6", "f.5", "f.9"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"6", "19", "24"))
```

Comment: sorry for so late response for your help, I'm now trying to understand your code and maybe I'll accept your answer or ask more in details. Thank you very much.

Comment: I finally understand your concise code, rich in content. I would manage to get all the gist in it. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad that it helped :)